# R: Understanding the "max" and "blur" options

Tags: r, leaflet, data-visualization, heatmap

I am working with the R programming language. Using the following code, I made an interactive map with the "leaflet" library :

```
Lat = round(runif(5000,43,44), 4)
Long = round(runif(5000,79,80), 4)
a <- rnorm(5000,100,10)

map_data <- data.frame(Lat, Long, a)
map_data$Long = -1 * map_data$Long

#load libraries
    library(leaflet)
    library(leaflet.extras)
    
#make heatmap for variable "a"
    leaflet(map_data) %>%
      addTiles(group="OSM") %>%
      addHeatmap(group="a", lng=~Long, lat=~Lat, max=.6, blur = 60)
```

[image]

Does anyone know if it is possible to understand the exact (math) formulas behind the coloring/shading in this map? I tried consulting the official documentation for the functions used to create this map (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/leaflet.extras/leaflet.extras.pdf) , but no where does it explain how the colors are finalized. I suspect that this somehow might be related to "kernel density estimation". Furthermore, I have a feeling that the "max" and the "blur" options are actually parameters used in the final coloring of this map.

Does anyone know if it is possible to understand the exact formula used behind the coloring?

Thanks

Comment: some useful links : https://www.geodose.com/2017/11/qgis-heatmap-using-kernel-density.html , https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/how-kernel-density-works.htm

Comment: Heh, cross-posted at https://www.reddit.com/r/gis/comments/nahcfn/understanding_how_heatmaps_work/